# Can I remove the "USB Configuration\KIES\UMS" splash-screen?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-kies

Everytime that I plug my Android smartphone on my USB PC port to recharge the batteries a splash-screen popup telling me to choose between "KIES and UMS-only configuration" and I need to chose "Cancel" to make the screen extinguish it light. There is some configuration to set one of these modes and cancel this choose process?

My smartphone is a Galaxy 551 with 2.2 Froyo Android.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my Galaxy S, turning on USB debug mode in `Settings -> Applications -> Development` turns off this notification.

Comment: Hmmm i will take a try then post the results here. Thank you

Comment: Glad to help :)